# How is $y' = x^2$ a differential equation if it doesn't contain a function $y$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

The way I learned differential equations is in the form

$$y' = y$$

for example. So for example, $y' = x$ or $y'' = 0$ was never given as examples as differential equations. However, according to my new textbook $y' = x^2$ is given as an example of a differential equation.

Can someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: yes, $y = \frac{x^3}{3} + C$ where $C = y(0)$

Comment: So a derivative of something is always a differential equation? Like whenever there's a y' or y'' somewhere in the equation, it's a differential equation?

Comment: I don't see how $y' = y'$ would work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. A differential equation is an expression involving a function (typically denoted $y(x)$) of a variable $x$, together with one or more of the derivatives of $y$. The coefficient of $y$ (or any derivative of $y$) can be zero in such an equation, so 
$$
y' = 0\\
y' = 3x y \\
y'' + y = 0 \\
y'' + x^2 = 9
$$
are all differential equations. Typically one requires that the coefficient of at least one of the derivatives of $y$ is nonzero, so you could say "It's an equation that specifies a function $y$ by saying something about some derivative of $y$."

Equations that don't involve anything except $y'$ are generally easy to solve: you isolate $y'$, getting something like 
$$
y' = x^2
$$
and then integrate both sides with respec to $x$, getting
$$
y(x) + C = \frac{x^3}{3} + K
$$
and then combine the two constants of integration into one to get
$$
y(x) = \frac{x^3}{3} + A.
$$

Of course, you can still have things like
$$
(y')^5 + y' + 1 = 0,
$$
where the "isolating $y'$" step may be effectively impossible. The "isolate $y'$ " strategy works best when $y'$ appears only to the first power. For other situations...you need other ideas, which is why we have whole books about ODEs. :)

Comment: I came up with $y' = y'$ as an expression with a derivative somewhere that is not really the same sort of thing as an ODE. Because the OP asked about that in comment

Comment: I think I sometimes explained what a differential equation was by saying that it was a description of a function that mentioned the function’s derivative.

Comment: I agree with both of you, partly. But I'd say that $0x = 0$ is an algebraic equation solved by all real numbers $x$, and in the same way, Will's equation is an ODE whose solution set consists of all differentiable functions. I know that this means that in my world, $y(x) = x + 2$ is a "differential equation", so my definition isn't ideal...but allowing this case doesn't seem like a mortal sin. Maybe venial. :) I'll edit slightly.

Comment: $
(y')^5 + y' + 1 = 0,
$  That's a good one

Answer (score 2):

Linear first order differential equations are of the form $y'=fy + h$.

What this means is that $f$ and $h$ are fixed functions in terms of $t$ and we have to find a function $y$ also in terms of $t$ that solves that system.

Your equation is the particular example in which $f$ is the constant $1$ function and $h$ is the constant $0$ function.

So your equation is not only a differential equation but it also fits into the nice family of linear differential equations.

Comment: This is not quite correct, since linear differential equations can involve higher-order derivatives of the function you denote as "y"...

Comment: fixed. ${}{}{}{}{}$